# Log the values of argparse in python

Tags: python, logging, argparse

I am trying to use both argparse and logging modules in python. I have a program that I run that has a lot of possible options and I've successfully implemented the argparse module to handle this task.

I'd like to keep a record of the values each option has when the program is run and send it to a log file. I tried the following couple of things, and I included the associated error I encounter as a comment beneath it.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input', action="store", default='fort.13', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

# First try:
logging.info("Input args: " + args)
# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Namespace' objects

# Second try:
for x in args:
  logging.info(x)
# TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `vars` to get the attributes of your parsed arguments:

```
for arg, value in sorted(vars(args).items()):
    logging.info("Argument %s: %r", arg, value)
```

This is detailed in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object).

Comment: I think you need to tweak it to be `logging.info("Argument %s: %r" % (n, v))`. One strange behavior though, when I add this to my code, it no longer outputs the .log file. when I comment it out and rerun, the log file remains. Any reason this should be doing something weird as to whether the log file is written?

Comment: @JBWhitmore: with the logging module, you don't do the string formatting yourself, you let logging do it.  I'm not sure what's going wrong with your log file...

Comment: Got it to work, silly mistake: I was pasting the code just above where I created the log file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
logging.info("Input args: %r", args)
```

Just dumps whole `Namespace` object containing all arguments in one line in log.