# How to display message after command line argument execution in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have following example script that uses `argparse`

```
import os
import numpy
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-C','--code',type=str, help='Choose solver')
    args = parser.parse_args()
 
    if args.code == 'compo1':
        print('This is solver version1')
    elif args.code == 'compo2':
        print('This is solver version2')
     
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

When I call in the command line

```
python3 main.py -code compo1
```

I get the output as expected:

```
This is solver version1
```

What I would like is a generic message after every execution, eg,

```
This is solver version1
INFO [solver compo1.py] completed success
```

I know that using another `print` would solve that, but can it be given as a default in `parse.add_arguments` or any other way ? such that whenever a flag is called by the user a message is displayed after execution ?

Comment: I don't think argparse has such a feature, so you have to do it with `print`

Comment: Whats wrong with using print?

Comment: After execution of what? You are printing after the execution of the argparse step?

Comment: @hpaulj I want the user to know that the execution of `-C` flag is complete via a message

Comment: What's that have to do with `argparse`?  It's not executing anything.  It's just parsing the input.

Comment: @hpaulj because I want a user-defined message after parsing the input

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logger instead print to log given arguments:

```py
for arg, value in sorted(vars(args).items()):
    logging.info("Argument %s: %r", arg, value)
```

See [Log the values of argparse in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571794/log-the-values-of-argparse-in-python).

Not related but useful to set the log-level from command-line [argparse-logging](https://pypi.org/project/argparse-logging/).